# Handling MySQL errors from Symfony application

Tags: php, error-handling, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I wish to know what is the best method to handle MySQL exceptions from a Symfony application, less said for example this one from normal enviroment(not dev):

> Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "500 Internal Server
>   Error".

which translate at _dev as follow:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '343434' for key 'rut'
```

how do yours handle with this kind of errors in order to show a message to end users or something more friendly?

Comment: Are you using an ORM?

Comment: @meijuh Yes, Doctrine that comes with Symfony

Comment: well doctrine is throwing an Exception so you can try/catch it in your controller. Keep in mind that you really want to be aware of this type of error ASAP (like in your example, a test is missing or your database schema is incorrect). A few things you need: 1.customise the 500 error page; 2.set-up email notifications so you are aware when a 500 happens; 3.you can also add extra try/catch for doctrine exceptions but keep in mind to log or email these so you know about it.

Comment: @François for now I handle using a try/catch but as you said is not the best, could you explain as a answer your reply? I google about the second step (2) and didn't find nothing related

Comment: Look for sfErrorNotifier2Plugin and sfErrorHandlerPlugin - they work very well. No need to write your own code for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to make a custom error page, and optionally create a custom error handler to alert you of the error.

First, create a custom error page, just create a file in `/path/to/project/config/error/error.html.php`.  Symfony will automatically use your error page instead of its own if it exists.

If you want to get a bit more advanced, you can add an event listener to handle uncaught exceptions.  To do this, edit `/path/to/project/config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php` and add a listener like so:

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()
  {
    //...
    $this->dispatcher->connect('application.throw_exception', array($this, 'listenToException'));
  }

  public function listenToException(sfEvent $event)
  {
    $handler = new myExceptionHandler($event);
    $handler->doSomethingHere();
  }
}
```

Then, all you have to do is create your own `myExceptionHandler` class that excepts an `sfEvent $event` parameter.  You can do whatever you want in here, I prefer to send an email to myself to tell me that an error has occurred.

Here is a brief example:

```
class myExceptionHandler
{
  protected $event;

  public function __construct(sfEvent $event)
  {
    $this->event = $event;
  }

  protected function getMailer()
  {
    return sfContext::getInstance()->getMailer();
  }

  public function notify()
  {
    $subject = 'Uncaught Exception';
    $body = $this->event->getSubject();

    $mailer = $this->getMailer();
    $mailer->composeAndSend('root@yourserver.com', 'you@youremail.com', $subject, $body);
  }
}
```

In this example, you would just call `$handler->notify()` from your project configuration and it would email you the stack trace.  You could also include other information like `$_SERVER` variables etc...